# Countable product of complete metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Someone that can give me a proof of that a countable product of complete metric spaces is complete ?

Comment: It depends on the metric on product you choose. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194951/is-the-product-of-polish-spaces-polish.

Comment: d(f,g) = sup_xd(f(x),g(x)) :)

Comment: Then see this discussion (note that your "metric" is not a metric): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249129/countable-product-of-polish-spaces

Answer (score 5):

Countable product of completely metrizable spaces is again completely metrizable.

1. Given a complete metric space $(Y,d)$, the metric $d'(x,y)= \min(1, d(x,y))$ is also complete since a sequence $(x_i)$ in $(Y,d)$ converges if and only if it converges in $(Y,d')$ and a sequence is Cauchy in $(Y,d)$ if and only if it is Cauchy in $(Y,d')$. Furthermore, the topologies on 
   $Y$ given by $d, d'$ are the same (Theorem 4.3.8 in [E]).
2. Suppose that $(X_i,\rho_i), i\in {\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of  metric spaces. For sequences 
   $x=(x_i)$, $y=(y_i)$ define 
   $$
   \rho(x,y)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} \rho_i(x_i, y_i). 
   $$
   By Theorem 4.2.2 in [E], $\rho$ metrizes the product topology on
   $$
   X=\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i.
   $$
3. Suppose that $(X_i,d_i)$ is a sequence of complete metric spaces. Then for $\rho_i= d'_i$, each $(X_i,\rho_i)$ is also complete and 
   the metric $\rho$ as above on the product space $X$ is complete as well (Theorem 4.2.2 in [E]).

Thus, the product of completely metrizable spaces is also completely metrizable.

[E] R.Engelking, "General Topology", Sigma Series in Pure Mathematics, 1989.