# What does uniform(non-uniform) convergence of a sequence by coordinate numbers in a metric space mean?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$m$ is defined as the metric space of all limited real sequences and the book states that convergence in $m$ means convergence by coordinates, uniformly according to coordinate numbers. $s$ is defined as the metric space of all real sequences and the book states that convergence in $s$ means convergence by coordinates non-uniformly by coordinate numbers. I can't figure out what uniformly/non-uniformly means in this context. I thought it didn't change much, but now I notice, that $s$ is said that is a complete space because the convergence in it is convergence by coordinates, but $m$'s completeness isn't shown the same way, instead, there is a complete proof of it.

Answer (score 0):

"The" (usual) topology on your space $m$ (the vector space of real bounded sequences) is the topology of normed vector space associated to the norm
$$\|(x_n)_n\|=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|x_n|.$$This way, a sequence $(x^{(k)})_k$ of bounded sequences $(x^{(k)}_n)_n$ converges to a bounded sequence $(x_n)_n$ iff $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|x^{(k)}_n-x_n|\right)=0,$ i.e.
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists K\quad\forall k\ge K\quad\forall n\quad|x^{(k)}_n-x_n|\le\epsilon$$
or equivalently:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists K\quad\forall n\quad\forall k\ge K\quad|x^{(k)}_n-x_n|\le\epsilon$$
This is what your book calls "convergence by coordinates, uniformly according to coordinate numbers".

It is a stronger requirement than "convergence by coordinates", which writes
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\forall n\quad\exists K\quad\forall k\ge K\quad\quad|x^{(k)}_n-x_n|\le\epsilon.$$
In the latter, $K$ is allowed to vary with $n,$ whereas in the former it is not.

On your space $s=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$  (the vector space of all real sequences), "the" (usual) topology, corresponding to this weaker notion of convergence, is the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). A [*countable* product of metric spaces is metrizable *in various ways*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361778), *some* of which (the usual ones) [preserve completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585791).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have a question though. So uniform convergence by coordinates is a stronger version of convergence by coordinates, right? If convergence in a space means convergence by coordinates then that space is complete. But why can't we directly deduce the same from the fact that convergence in $m$ means uniform convergence by coordinates? In other words, if convergence in $m$ is stronger than convergence in $s$ and $s$ is complete because convergence in $s$ is convergence by coordinates, then why can't we deduce the same way that $m$ is complete?

Comment: 1. Completeness is not a topological property but a metric one (or more generally a uniform one, but forget). 2. Not every *countable* product of *metric* spaces $(E_n,d_n)$, even equipped with one of the "usual" metrics associated to the $d_n$'s, is complete: a necessary condition is that the $(E_n,d_n)$'s are complete. 3. If you have 2 metrics $d$ and $d'$ on a space and if convergence for $d$ implies convergence for $d'$, completeness for $d'$ does not imply completeness for $d$ because even if a $d$-Cauchy sequence is $d'$-Cauchy hence $d'$-convergent, it may be non-$d$-convergent.